# NSTextViewDelegate crashing

Tags: swift, macos, nstextview

I have a small project with an NSTextview and a delegate that catches changes in text, as below. The object EditViewHandler works fine when it's a global but crashes when text is added to the view if it's local to viewDidLoad(). So this is obviously the wrong way to do it but what would be the correct way of doing this:

```
@IBOutlet var EditPaneOutlet: NSTextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let e = EditViewHandler( EditPaneOutlet: EditPaneOutlet )
}

class EditViewHandler : NSObject, NSTextViewDelegate {

    var EditPaneOutlet: NSTextView! = nil

        init( EditPaneOutlet: NSTextView ) {
            super.init()
            self.EditPaneOutlet = EditPaneOutlet
            self.EditPaneOutlet!.delegate = self
        }

    func textDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
        print( "text changed")
    }
}
```